# Cannot recognize this.state.data

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react class that uses a table view and attempts to access `this.state.data` when one of the rows is clicked. The issue is `this.state` is null in the callback function for the row selection. but when I click another UI element to log `this.state.data' it logs the data (correctly). Why is this?

Here's my code:

```
class NS2  extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      typeIndex: props.typeIndex,
      data: tableData
    };

  }

  getData() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
  }

  getOptions() {
    return {
      onRowClick: function(row) {
        alert('data: ' + this.state.data);
        //alert(`You click row name: ${row.name}`);
      },
      onRowDoubleClick: function(row) {
        alert(`You double click row name: ${row.name}`);
      }
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={12} md={6}>
              <BootstrapTable data={this.state.data} version='4' options={ this.getOptions() }>
                <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='name' isKey>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='img' dataFormat={imageFormatter}>Images</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='speed'>Speed</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='units'>Units</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='boxes'>Boxes</TableHeaderColumn>
              </BootstrapTable>

            </Col>
            <Col  sm={12} md={6}>
              <a className="btn" onClick={() => this.getData()}>
                <span>View Selection</span>
              </a>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>

      </div>

    );
  }

}
```

**Note:** The button calls `getData()` and it displays the correct data. The callback for the row selection is in `getOptions` and it returns null (throws error) for `this.state.data`: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to not binding your functions to your component

try this

```
class NS2  extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  typeIndex: props.typeIndex,
  data: tableData
};
this.getOptions = this.getOptions.bind(this)
this.onRowClick = this.onRowClick.bind(this)
}

getData() {
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
}
onRowClick(row) {
   alert('data: ' + this.state.data);
}
onRowDoubleClick(row) {
   alert(`You double click row name: ${row.name}`);
}
getOptions() {
  return {
    onRowClick: this.onRowClick,
    onRowDoubleClick: this.onRowDoubleClick
  };
 }
...//rest of your code
```

since you're not using "this" in onRowDoubleClick function,its not required to bind "this" to the component

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind as suggested by Avinash and if you don’t want to split  `getOptions` you can do this:

```
getOptions() {
    const self = this;
    return {
      onRowClick: function(row) {
        alert('data: ' + self.state.data);
        //alert(`You click row name: ${row.name}`);
      },
      onRowDoubleClick: function(row) {
        alert(`You double click row name: ${row.name}`);
      }
    };
  }
```